# Create a scatterplot with errorbars with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I was trying to make a scatterplot and add some error bars to the points but I don't know how to.

```
p <- ggplot(data = success, aes(x = Percent, y = No.Fleas)) + 
  geom_point(col = "blue") + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) + 
  geom_errorbar(x = x, ymin = 9.997, ymax = 52.21)
p
```

Comment: Hello Marta! Please add your data to the question by adding the output of `dput(success)`

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am intrigued. how are errorbars for a scatterplot supposed to look like?